# Erlang: what is the difference between "include_lib" and "include"?

Tags: erlang

What is the difference between "include_lib" and "include" ?

E.g.

`-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl")`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The way the documentation describes [the difference between include and include_lib](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html) is:

> `include_lib` is similar to `include`, but should not point out an absolute file. Instead, the first path component (possibly after variable substitution) is assumed to be the name of an application.
>
> Example:
>
> `-include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").`
>
> The code server uses code:lib_dir(kernel) to find the directory of the current (latest) version of Kernel, and then the subdirectory include is searched for the file file.hrl.

So in your example, you dont need to point out the version of eunit that you include, you are including the latest eunit.hrl of the eunit:s that exists in your library path.

Comment: I believe you can also use include_lib to include files you want from a specific version of an installed application.

Answer (score 20):

One difference which is not obvious at first is that `-include` and `-include_lib` use a different set of paths when looking for header files. `-include_lib` in fact uses the code path, not the header file path.

Hence, the flag `erlc` expects to add a path to the `-include` search path is `-I`; the flag for `-include_lib` is `-pa`/`-pz`.

Already mentioned is the fact that using `-include_lib` saves us from specifying (and therefore tying) the module to a specific library version.

Furthermore, there's a convention that *internal headers* are stored inside the `src/` subdirectory of a project and included using `-include`. *External headers* (intended to be used by other libraries/projects) files are stored in `include/` and included using `-include_lib`.