# What is an Erlang hrl file?

Tags: erlang, header-files

What is an `.hrl` file in Erlang/OTP? Is it some sort of library mechanism?

Comment: After reading the link you showed maybe me and you should "agree to disagree" on what the definition of "readability" is. But thanks for the link anyway :)

Comment: @dustin: i stumbled over them in "programming erlang" on page 60. so -- there is indeed the possibility to know of the existence without knowing the purpose or contents.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A "header file" akin to a "C" include file.

One needs to invoke the `-include` directive from an `.erl` file to use them.  Can contain any valid Erlang code.

Comment: You can also use `-include_lib` to include a header file from another application.

Comment: @zed: yes, see the following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847918/erlang-what-is-the-difference-between-include-lib-and-include

Answer (score 9):

The actual doc is http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html

Answer (score 7):

hrl files are simply erlang "header", that is files containing common definitions that are intended to be included by .erl files.