# What is the best way to include a header file (wx.hrl for example) in a release using rebar

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets, rebar

I am preparing a release for an application using rebar, and I wonder what is the usual way to include header file from standard library. In my case, it is the wx.hrl file, which is included with its full absolute path in my code.

I guess that it is not the right way :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-include_lib("wx/include/wx.hrl").
```

This makes the preprocessor look for the latest version of the `wx` application in the code path. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847918/erlang-what-is-the-difference-between-include-lib-and-include) for more details.

Comment: thank you, I have tried several spelling with / and \\, but I always omitted the first wx...