# How to include file from Erlang/OTP module

Tags: erlang

I need to include some head files from Erlang/OTP module, is there any practical method other than using absolute path like

`-include("/usr/lib64/erlang/lib/snmp-4.25/include/snmp_types.hrl").`

Comment: Could the link following help you???
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847918/erlang-what-is-the-difference-between-include-lib-and-include

Comment: From the accepted answer above, "-include" should search include file from "code:lib_dir". But erlc report ""can't find include file" on `-include("snmp/include/snmp_types.hrl").`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to include a header file (wx.hrl for example) in a release using rebar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363244/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-a-header-file-wx-hrl-for-example-in-a-release)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ref the Question: [Erlang: what is the difference between "include_lib" and "include"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847918/erlang-what-is-the-difference-between-include-lib-and-include)

you should use `-include_lib(XXX)` instead of `-include(XXX)` if include from its system library.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use:

```
-include_lib("snmp/include/snmp_types.hrl").
```

> include_lib is similar to include, but should not point out an
>   absolute file. Instead, the first path component (possibly after
>   variable substitution) is assumed to be the name of an application.
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> -include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").
>
> The code server uses code:lib_dir(kernel) to find the directory of the current (latest) version of Kernel, and then the subdirectory
> ```
>
> include is searched for the file file.hrl.