# Header files location for an Erlang/OTP application

Tags: erlang, directory-structure, erlang-otp

Should I place `.hrl` header files of an Erlang/OTP application in the `/src` or the `/include` directory?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847918/erlang-what-is-the-difference-between-include-lib-and-include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html

> - **src** - Required. Contains the Erlang source code, the source of the .app file and **internal include files used by the application itself**. [...]
> - **include** - Optional. Used for public include files that must be **reachable from other applications**.

---

This is also explained by: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-July/045516.html

> **Use Case 1:**
>   Your project has `-define`d constants, parse transforms, etc. which are **required for others** to use your code. Examples include `qlc` or `webmachine`.
>
> **Solution:** Put your `.hrl` files in `/include`. As long as your project is on the code path then clients of your code can use `-include_lib()` to load the `.hrl` files.
>
> ---
>
> **Use Case 2:** You've centralised common constants, etc. in a `.hrl` file. These constants are intended to be used **internally** by your project code. This means at no time will any client need access to them.
>
> **Solution:** Put your `.hrl` files in `/src`. Your code can use `-include()` to pull in the `.hrl` files.
>
> ---
>
> Keep in mind that both include directives are compile-time constructs. You can put all of your header files in `/src`, compile your code using `-include()`, and then selectively "export" the header files you want to publish by copying them into `/include`. I do this a lot since it makes my compile process easier -- no code path to futz with -- and it makes my client code cleaner -- they can use `-include_lib()` to find my public header files.
>
> --Kevin